# Ionic ion-view load before parse.com data arrive

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework.
I am creating app,where I have used Ionic framework and Parse.com as backend..

Problem:
I have created service to fetch the customer data(name,address,cust_photo..) from the parse table and this service is called within controller function than this function I have used in ion-view's div tag (ng-init="customer_data()") but my ion-view some display data or sometime not I think because of ion-view render before parse.com data available..

In service and controller console.log(customerdata) is displayed..

I have read about Promise, watch but does not know how to use...

```
.service {
    function() {
        //parse.com query method to get data from parse
        return customerdata; 
    }
}


.controller {
    function(...) {
        $scop.customer_data() {
            ......
        }
    }
}

<ion-view>
<div ng-init="customer_data()">

//customer info....`


</div>
</ion-view>
```

How can i solve this issue? Can you give me some code snippet?

Comment: put your service function into controller

Comment: Thnks for reply but this will become repetitive task, I have created service to make repetitive task less..

Answer (score 1):

Promises, watches and callbacks are three possible ways to solve your problem. I will describe the callback solution.

To make sure to have the retrieved values in your $scope, simply pass a callback function to your service method:

```
.service {
    function() {
        //parse.com query method to get data from parse
        getCustomerData: function(callback){
          //get values
          callback(values);
        } 
    }
}


.controller {
    function(...) {
        $scope.customer_data() {
            myService.getCustomerData(function(values){
              $scope.customer_data = values;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I have already used callback approach. I have found issue. After login first screen is "Home", data does not displayed but click on menu(Not any menu item only menu, top left) data displayed in Home screen.. may be home screen not reload properly..??